Undocumented rate limit? "Resource has been exhausted" after just a few hundred emails
We are importing e-mails via the Gmail API using a service account (domain-wide delegation) for Google Workspace. After importing around 200-300 e-mails for a single account, we always get an error "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)." in the mornings with the reason being: "rateLimitExceeded", although it should not be possible that the limit has been exceeded:
Our process is: First we get all the message-ids with history.list with one request.
Then we iterate over the list of messages and send a batch request for 45 emails each with messages.get. After each batch we implement a waiting period of 4 seconds before the next request is sent. From our understanding this should be well below any rate limit.
Also according to the docs https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota we have 250 quota units per user per second.
Our usage should only add up to a maximum of 227 though (history.list = 2, messages.get = 5 * 45).
Some accounts will have several hundred e-mails that should be imported and after around 200-300 we get the above mentioned error message.
We have tried to increase the timeout and decrease the batch size, but that did not work either.
Are we missing something? Is there some other / undocumented rate limit we should be aware of? Since we never use more than the 250 quota limit in our import and only one request every 4 seconds, how can it be that we still exceed some limit?
Our usage statistics also do not indicate that we are anywhere close to exceeding any (known) limits: Screenshot of Cloud Console
We'd be grateful for any advice!
--- EDIT
Full error message:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}


what is the full error message there should be more then just rateLimitExceeded

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I added the full error message.

Okay these kins of errors are really hard to track down.

Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).

Implies to me that you have hit a hard limit to the number of something that can be done in a day.
If this is true the number would reset after midnight West Cost USA time.  So that should be easy enough to test.
If it does then checking this page Usage limits may give you an idea of what limit you are hitting.
If its not that then it could be flood protection.  The thing is normally if its flood protection google will tell you which one you are hitting and you just need to slow down.
To test if its this one wait thirty minutes and see if it will run again if it does then its probably this and you just need to implement Exponential_backoff in your code.
However if you are using one of the standard google client libaries you may want to check most of them have Exponential backoff baked into them already.
Not sure if this is a help but it may give you some ideas on what to check for.
